# Get category id

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, category, blocks, magento2.3

How can I get `ID` from this code which is typed into `CMS` page content?

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryList" category_id="49" template="Vendor_Module::subcategorylist.phtml"}}
```

I need to get `ID` into my `Block` file.

Which classes I have to inject and what methods I need to write into `Block` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this in your block file and phtml file

> $this->getData("category_id");

Answer (score 5):

In Magento 2 You can get Category Id by using following code

```
$categoryid = $block->getData('category_id');
```

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 5):

**At Block, you can get that parameter value by**

```
    if($this->hasData('category_id'))
    {
        $categoryid = $this->getData('category_id');
    }
```